# How do I make Microsoft Outlook show the padlock icon on private appointments in the calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

Microsoft Outlook used to display a padlock icon together with the subject line for appointments that were tagged as private.  Now, it will show the padlock icon on the day and week views, but it does not show it on the month view of the calendar, even though I have Show High Detail selected for the view.  I want to be able to see at a glance from any calendar view whether or not a particular appointment has been designated as private.  It used to just happen by default.  I don't know why it is not rendering the padlock icon on the month view now.

Comment: A possible workaround could be to use conditional formatting to change the colour of private appointments

Answer (score 0):

From: http://oit2.utk.edu/helpdesk/kb/entry/343/

Outlook 2010
In Calendar view, select either New Appointment or New Meeting. 
Create the appointment or meeting by filling out the window; click Save. 
Looking at your calendar, find the appointment or meeting and right-click on it; choose Private from the drop-down menu. 
When you view your calendar, you will see a lock on the private appointment or meeting; in Month view, the lock may be hidden due to the reduced size of each day’s calendar slot.

Aka a new and improved feature... which begs the question, if it's new, how can it be improved?